# How do I display the classification error for each row of a dataset? XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost

I was able to get the values of parameters accuracy, recall, f1, precision for each class. But I can't figure out how to implement error for each line.

Comment: Any code or attempt you have tried?

Comment: My code is above. This is all that I managed to do.

Answer (score 0):

if what you're looking for is probability of each class, your deal is

```
model.predict_proba(test_data_x)
```

and the return result will give you array of probability for each class.

Comment: I got error.AttributeError: 'Booster' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

Comment: @PriestGapon using `'objective':'multi:softprob' `in your params will return probability array instead of a predicted result. However in this case you do lose your predict result itself, so you'll need extra process to turn array of probabilities to your actual `y_pred`. You could also consider 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589011/get-probability-from-xgb-train